# Azure AD Authentication Pass user details from client to API

Tags: azure, .net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have a .net core web application which is secured with Azure AD using Security groups to lock down access to certain controllers, Ill refer to this as the client.

The client communicates with an API which needs to be secured, all of the documentation I have seen talks about using azure AD to secure the API but from what I understand this means that the API will verify that the client is authorized to use it NOT that the user who is authenticated into the client.

Ideally, we want to be able to have the API secured so that different security groups have access to different endpoints.

tldr; A user authenticates to a client the client communicates with an API, we need the users details to be passed to the API.

If someone could point me in the right direction this would be great.

Comment: Are you trying to restrict users based on their  group  to access API?

Comment: Yes, thats what we want. So a user can call an endpoint on the API (Via the client) and if they are not in a specific AD group they will be denied.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in Azure AD where you can assign users to particular app. Please follow the below steps.

1. Login to **Azure portal** and go to Active Directory->Enterprise applications
2. Select All Applications to view a list of all your applications.
3. Select the application you want to assign a user or security group
   to from the list.
4. Select **Users and groups** and assign user or security group you want to give access for application
   [image]
5. On the application's **Overview page**, select **Properties** from the
   application’s left-hand navigation menu.
6. Locate the setting **User assignment required?** and set it to **Yes**. When
   this option is set to **Yes**, users in the tenant must first be
   assigned to this application, or they won't be able to sign-in to
   this application.
7. click **Save** to save this configuration change.

Comment: Sorry, bit of a misunderstanding, how does the client pass that users details to the API?

Comment: As I understand the user authenticates to the client. The client then authenticates to the API.  But how do I get that users details to the API?

Comment: It is possible with [Openid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc) connect.you need to mention your auth scope as open id.